# Can be LINQ rewritten to avoid MissingMemberException with 'Option Infer Off'?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, option-infer

This is simple encoder of string into a literal which is acceptable in regex. Works well with `Option Infer On`, but crashes in rumtime with `Option Infer Off`, producing
`MissingMemberException: No default member found for type VB$AnonymousDelegate_1(Of Char, String)`.

Can the LINQ expression be rewritten to work even with `Option Infer Off`? I would like to keep it off because I think there is a risk turning `Option Infer On` in a large legacy project/library. (Or am I wrong?)

This is the code of the method:

```
Shared Function EscapeLiteralForRegexPattern(inputString As String) As String

  '*** Based on Escape(). Keep them in sync.
  Const dontEscapeFrom = &H20
  Const dontEscapeTo = &H7E
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString) Then Return inputString

  Const escaper As String = "\"
  Const escapePattern As String = escaper & escaper
  Const tabPattern As String = escaper & "t"
  Const crPattern As String = escaper & "r"
  Const lfPattern As String = escaper & "n"
  Const unicodePattern As String = escaper & "u{0:X4}"
  Const asciiPattern As String = escaper & "x{0:X2}"

  Dim ConvertChar = Function(c As Char) As String
             If c = escaper Then Return escapePattern
             Dim ac As Integer = AscW(c)
             If ac >= dontEscapeFrom AndAlso ac <= dontEscapeTo Then
               Return Regex.Escape(c)
             End If
             Dim result As String = String.Format(If(ac < &H80, asciiPattern, unicodePattern), ac)
             If dontEscapeFrom = 0 Then Return result
             Select Case c
               Case vbTab
                 Return tabPattern
               Case vbCr
                 Return crPattern
               Case vbLf
                 Return lfPattern
               Case Else
                 Return result
             End Select
           End Function

  Return String.Join(String.Empty, inputString.Select(Function(c) ConvertChar(c)).ToArray())

End Function
```

This is LINQ change I tried (but the problem remained):

```
  Return String.Join(String.Empty, inputString.Select(Function(c As Char) As String
                              Return ConvertChar(c)
                            End Function).ToArray())
```

Comment: Downvoters: could you please leave a feedback what is wrong with the question?

Comment: You have a bug in your code, you are comparing apples and oranges.  Trivially found by putting Option Strict On at the top of the source code file.  With Option Infer On, the compiler can turn apples into oranges.  If you turn it off then, no, you get apple sauce.

Comment: Wasn't me, but are you trying to replicate [RegEx.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton - `RegEx.Escape` is part of this method as you can see and it does only minimum replacements (doc says: Escapes a minimal set of characters (see the list)...) but I need to have \r, \n, \t in human-readable form, that `RegEx.Escape` won't do for me. Also not speaking of Non-Ascii characters.

Comment: @HansPassant - GREAT! Thank you for helpful hint Hans! I reminded myself of the fact I should test new methods ***outside*** that old big library because that one forces me into `Strict Off` and `Explicit Off` (which I hate both). Then sometimes I forget during coding that they are off, exactly like in this case.

Comment: @miroxlav That minimal set of characters includes "white space" which does \f, \n, \r, \t, \v, so you could reduce your code a little.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - thank you for your advice Andrew. I overlooked that fact and I appreciate your note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to [image: Hans Passant] – see his comment.

I was adding the code into legacy bulky library which needs to have `Option Explicit Off`, `Option Strict Off` until rewritten.

I forgot they are off and therefore missed some explicit type declarations during coding. After `Option Explicit On` and  `Option Strict On` and all requested corrections, the entire problem with `MissingMemberException` went away.

Comment: Something Hans didn’t mention, you can set Option Strict and Option Infer on a per file basis.  Anytime you are dealing with a legacy project that had these Off on a per project basis should have them added on a per file basis and then set to On whenever you get a chance to clean up a file.